# How to change Metro Theme in runTimes

Tags: c#

in my application user can select any theme to apply.i use sample Metro Dot Net Bar.but i don't know how can change Theme in metro Form?I need your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: styleManager1.MetroColorParameters.ThemeName = (MetroColorGeneratorParameters)themeDefault; but it not correct

Comment: check this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f91a11d6-6e56-4978-8acd-21ae9f3c3a6e/how-to-switch-themes-in-metro-style-apps-at-runtime?forum=winappswithcsharp